# Using AWS SNS to push notifications to React Native Mobile [ANDROID] (optional use of FCM)

Tags: android, amazon-web-services, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging, amazon-sns

I developed a simple pipeline by chaining restful HTTP call from AWS API Gateway to lambda and finally to SNS. My next objective is to trigger push notification to mobile (Android) for every SNS topic triggered. The mobile client specifically developed using React Native. I know that there are several approaches
a) Using aws-sdk to get pushed SNS data
b) Using FCM to get pushed SNS data, but requires SNS to link with FCM.

I did many research on the above, but there seem no clear guidance on how to set it up, because many of them touch on native solution ie Android native or IOS native.

Questions:
1. Which one would be better approach, OR is there any other better approach?
2. Based on the chosen approach, could you kindly provide simple and clear steps on how to set up (step by step with good samples/examples are appreciated)?

Thanks for kind helpers!

Answer (score 4):

I am currently working on something similar. I think you can accomplish what you are looking for by using the library 'react-native-push-notification'. There is a tutorial for it-https://medium.com/@xap5xap/show-push-notifications-on-react-native-app-a613a5a2c159. I hope it helps.